# What dangers torrent games carry?

Tags: malware

There are many games that are free on torrent. Is it actually free or you just pay not with your money? Can it have a malware?

Comment: It's not free, it's piracy. Yes if you download random executables from the Internet they can have malware in them.

Comment: It's sad that "torrenting" is synonymous with "piracy" these days. A trusted and legitimately free game distributed via torrent would not carry the same risk as a pirated one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience It will carry malware. Many websites add malware to the crack or the .exe of the game to infect your PC. Don't forget that the creator of the crack (Ex. SKIDROW) can add malware to the crack so, you can't be 100% secure that the game is not infected.
Take care too that, in many countries piracy is illegal.

Comment: I do know that piracy is illegal, and in my country game piracy is very common(average salary is 200$, game costs 60$). I don`t play games anymore but recently got interested why someone would steal the game and share it for free.

Answer (score 1):

More often than not, they contain some type of malware - sometimes unnoticeable and will barely affect your computer. While you are extremely unlikely to get arrested for downloading pirated software/games due to the large amount of people that do it, I suggest not downloading anything pirated as it's still illegal.

Having a good antivirus will often not help at all since most cracks would require the user to temporarily disable the antivirus which will open the door for any malware that it may contain.

Answer (score -3):

Just read about RAT and you will know you should never trust anything that you download through torrent .

Comment: ... or, just read about ransomware, or any malware for that matter. I'm not sure how focusing on this one, narrowly defined danger works as a standalone answer.